# How to change parent property value

Tags: php, oop, extends

I have a parent class Base

```
abstract class Base
 {
    protected $prop1 = null;

    protected $prop2 = null;
 }
```

And in the child class I want to change the both of property

```
class Child extends Base
 {


    public function method1($val1, $val2)
    {
        $this->prop1 = $val1;
        $this->prop2 = $val2;
    }

    public function method2()
    {
        echo prop1;
        echo prop2;
    }

 }
```

Is there any way to get changed values after calling first method of child class and after when I calling the second method of the child class? I tried to do that but I'm getting not changed values in this exsample thay are null's.

Comment: The `$this->prop1` syntax is both for writing **and** reading. `prop1` would be a constant, as in `define('prop1', 'foo');`.

Comment: you are doing right, but call `$this->your properties` in both

Comment: sorry its my mistak im doing that I forgot to write $this in my question .
     
I' creating an object $child = new Child() and after calling first method im calling the second but the second method print null but i want to print values which ared changed in method1

Answer (score 1):

In child class method2 you are not referring to actual properties.
use `$` otherwise `php` will understand it as a `constant`

```
<?php

     abstract class Base
     {
        protected $prop1 = null;

        protected $prop2 = null;
     }

     class Child extends Base
     {

        public function method1($val1, $val2)
        {
            $this->prop1 = $val1;
            $this->prop2 = $val2;
        }

        public function method2()
        {
            echo $this->prop1; 
            echo $this->prop2;
        }

     }

     $child = new Child();
     $child->method1(30, "ABC");
     $child->method2(); //will show 30ABC

    ?>
```

Comment: sorry its my mistak im doing that I forgot to write $this in my question

Comment: I' creating an object $child = new Child() and after calling first method im calling the second but the second method print null

Comment: `$child = new Child();
 $child->method1(30, "ABC");
 $child->method2();` working fine

Comment: but i changed them by calling method1 befor calling method2

Comment: see the full code. double check that you don't have some other line making trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$this->prop1` to read the `prop1` property:

```php
class Child extends Base{

    public function method1 ($val1, $val2) {
        $this->prop1 = $val1;
        $this->prop2 = $val2;
    }

    public function method2 () {
        echo $this->prop1;
        echo $this->prop2;
    }

}
```

Read about OOP in PHP in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php).

Comment: sorry its my mistak im doing that I forgot to write $this in my question . I' creating an object $child = new Child() and after calling first method im calling the second but the second method print null but i want to print values which ared changed in method

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle prop1 and prop2 as class properties. Therefore - object scope/context - you have to write in code (whenever you read/write their values) as you have done it in method1():

```
public function method2() {
    echo $this->prop1;
}
```

Comment: sorry its my mistak im doing that I forgot to write $this in my question . I' creating an object $child = new Child() and after calling first method im calling the second but the second method print null but i want to print values which ared changed in method

Comment: I've tested your code an it is working fine! See here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c146f8bfa71948f39ab7a71bc69a65fa4250e2a6